# Who were the survivors in Danganronpa?

Tags: danganronpa

In the last episode, many survivors were shown in the outside world. Who were these people? Is there any reference anywhere telling about these people, who they were and how they managed to survive?

Comment: AFAIK no one that died, survived. They did say there was some leaked information that those who participated and died, didn't actually die or something but besides that what is displayed during the anime is recollections of what happened before the school turned into a survival school or so I think. Like they were enrolled there before it became what it was and had their memories erased or partially removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen the anime yet, but in the game's version of events the survivors  who are living in the outside world are the general public who have fallen into despair (and somehow gained monokuma heads)

[image]

You can see them rioting in the image above, and it wouldn't be a wild stretch of the imagination to say that they were probably looting stores also. [note the broken window at the very right] which is where they could get themselves provisions and other necessities.

The academy was sealed off by the students themselves so that they would not succumb to the miserable world outside.

[image]

At the end of the game, the students mention that there are people out there who are still clinging onto remnants of hope, and that they will go out, meet them and join forces. But as far as I can tell, it's just conjecture on their part.